# List of all Collatz sequences from 1 to n

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to program a function that calculates the Collatz sequences of all the numbers from 1 to n. The result should be in a form of list of lists.

Something like this:

```
collatzSeqs 5 => [[1], [2, 1], [3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1], [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]]
```

My code looks like this:

```
nextCollatz:: Int-> Int
nextCollatz n 
 | n < 1 = error "number lower than 1"
 | n == 1 = 1
 | mod n 2 == 0 = div n 2
 | otherwise =  3 * n + 1 -- Calculates the next Collatz number


collatzSeq:: Int-> [Int] 
collatzSeq n
 | n < 1 = error "number lower than 1"
 | n == 1 = [1]
 | otherwise = n:collatzSeq (nextCollatz n) -- Makes a sequence a collatz sequence
```

The idea that I had to program the `collatzSeqs` was to take the `head[collatzSeq]` and somehow continue doing it in a recursive form and then take the result and insert it in a new list that is probably empty.

To illustrate my idea I've tried to code it down: (It doesn't work)

```
collatzSeqs :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
collatzSeqs n = collatzSeq head[1..n]: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your try of `collatzSeqs` we see that it takes an input `n` and returns a list of lists containing the number `1`. This originates of the fact that there is actually no recursive call going on here. All the function does is take an integer and return the collatz sequence for 1 consed onto an empty list like this:

```
-- example 3:
collatzSeqs 3 = collatzSeq (head [1..n]) : [] = collatzSeq 1 : [] = [1] : [] = [[1]]
```

We can see that for any input n the function will just return `[[1]]`. The problem is that no recursion is going on here. If we would rewrite this function we would get something like this:

```
collatzSeqs n = collatzHelp n 1
  where
    collatzHelp n m
      | n == m = collatzSeq n : []
      | otherwise = collatzSeq m : collatzHelp n (m+1)
```

But this is way to complex, there clearly must be something simpler because all we want to do is just take a function and apply it to every element in a list. And lucky you, there actually is!

Your `collatzSeqs` is actually just a simple map:

```
collatzSeqs n = map collatzSeq [1..n]
```

A map is a function which takes a function and a list and returns a list of results of the function being applied to every element of the given list. You can imagine it to be defined like this:

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

In this case our function we want to be calculated for each element is `collatzSeq` and our list should be the numbers from one to n because we want the function applied to every number between including 1 and n.

Answer (score 0):

Momoized via knot-tying.

```
import Control.Applicative ((<*>))
import Control.Monad (forM_)

collatz' :: [[Integer]]
collatz' = map ((:) <*> next) [1..]
 where
    next n = collatz . fromInteger $ case n `quotRem` 2 of
     (d, 0) -> d
     (_, 1) -> 3 * n + 1

collatz :: Int -> [Integer]
collatz = (collatz' !!) . pred

main :: IO ()
main = do
    nStr <- getLine
    let n = read nStr
    forM_ [1..n] $ \i -> do
        putStr $ show i
        putStr ": "
        putStr . show . take n $ collatz i
        putStrLn "..."
```

It calculates the Collatz successor of each Integer exactly once.

Doesn't stop the sequence at 1, and instead loops, which is why the `take`.  Refactoring to stop at 1 is left as an exercise.

Comment: Case uses `->` and not `=`. Also, you might want to add a base case for next: `next 1 = []`. That way you could let your main function show the whole sequences instead of just the first `n` numbers in each sequence, which is what OP asks for.

Comment: Actually, the OP asks for "function that calculates the Collatz sequences of all the numbers from 1 to n".  The Collatz sequence for 1 is an infinite list [1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2...].  [[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)]  The code the OP posted doesn't calculate the Collatz sequence correctly, but my code does.

Comment: True, but 1 is often taken as the base case as the trivial cycle is quite uninteresting. And the example output OP posted shows quite clearly what the OP wants.